# "Ibus-table" a proprieatary software, is in Ubuntu Main Repository

Tags: 18.04, proprietary, official-repositories, free-software

In "Ubuntu Software" GUI to install and remove software, it says that `Ibus-table` has propritary license and the source is `Ubuntu Bionic Main` repository.

But, [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu), it is mentioned that: "Main is Canonical-supported free and open-source software."

Can anybody clarify this? Also, is it a necessity for the functioning of Ubuntu? Can it be removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu Software may be wrong with license type.

As you can get the [source code of the package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/ibus-table) it is open-source.

About license see [source code repository in upstream (Debian)](https://salsa.debian.org/input-method-team/ibus-table/blob/master/COPYING) and  [real upstream](https://github.com/kaio/ibus-table/blob/master/COPYING).

> [image: ibus-table/COPYING]

**It is GNU LGPL software.**